# 301 Redirect from OpenCMS to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, opencms

I just migrated a website from OpenCMS to Wordpress as its platform. What Im trying to now is redirect the pages one by one using .htaccess found in the cpanel.

Question is how do I redirect this url https://www.southville.edu.ph/opencms/opencms/Southville/v2/Webpages/ContactUs/ContactUsForm.jsp

to here
https://www.southville.edu.ph/contact-us/

I've tried adding this code below in the .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /opencms/opencms/Southville/v2/Webpages/ContactUs/ContactUsForm.jsp https://southville.edu.ph/contact-us
```

but it wouldn't work. This is my first time migrating a website. Hopefully you guys can help me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Are there any working rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: Hi @anubhava my .htaccess is in cpanel.

Comment: You may post your full .htaccess in the question